# Solr adds unwanted MatchAllDocsQuery and I don't know why

Tags: solr

In my company we have a test string, which we use to ensure escaping issues are handled correctly throughout our many components:

```
!"§$%&/()?ß><öä€ü\ÖÄÄÜ#'
```

When I add a document to Solr with that title, all is well.
I now try to query that document using the same string, but with all special query parameters escaped ([see here for details](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters)):

```
!\"§$%&\/\(\)\?ß><öä€ü\\ÖÄÄÜ#'
```

Surprisingly, **all documents in my index match** that query!

I can see in the debug output (see below), that Solr adds a MatchAllDocsQuery after my actual query. That's why all documents match, but the big question is:

**Why does Solr add that match-all query?** It doesn't make any sense to me.

Funnily enough, when I remove one of the escaping backslashes (e.g. the very first one before the double-quote), the query works like a charm and only finds my one expected document. For whatever reason, Solr then does not add that match_all query anymore.

```
!"§$%&\/\(\)\?ß><öä€ü\\ÖÄÄÜ#'
```

Any ideas???

Debug info:

```
"rawquerystring": "!\\\"§$%&\\/\\(\\)\\?ß><öä€ü\\\\ÖÄÄÜ#'",
"querystring": "!\\\"§$%&\\/\\(\\)\\?ß><öä€ü\\\\ÖÄÄÜ#'",
"parsedquery": "(+(-DisjunctionMaxQuery((((de_all:ss de_all:oa de_all:u >de_all:oaau)~4) | ((en_all:ß en_all:öä en_all:ü en_all:öääü)~4) | string_all:\"§$%&/()?ss><oa€u\\oaau#')) +MatchAllDocsQuery(*:*)))/no_coord",
"parsedquery_toString": "+(-(((de_all:ss de_all:oa de_all:u de_all:oaau)~4) | ((en_all:ß en_all:öä en_all:ü en_all:öääü)~4) | string_all:\"§$%&/()?ss><oa€u\\oaau#') +*:*)"
```

Request handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/custom" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">none</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="qf">de_all^1 en_all^1 string_all^1</str>
       <str name="fl">id,score</str>
       <str name="indent">false</str>
     </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

If you need any other info, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, stupid mistake: I forgot to escape the leading '!', which makes this a query with a single negated phrase. AFAIK those are handled internally with a match all query.